# Big-O complexity of multiple variables with different functions

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to figure out what is the total Big-O complexity of a problem with multiple variables and different mathematical functions.

The two big steps in the problem takes `O(n*m)` and `O(n*logn)`. Both `n` and `m` are independent and can be very big or very small.

What is the correct complexity? Is it `O(n*m)`? `O(n*logn)`? Or `O(n*m+n*logn)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two big steps happen one after the other (not in parallel), the best we can say is that it takes $O(nm + n\log(n))$ time to complete. If you knew more information of how $n$ and $m$ relate to eachother then you could simplify more.

Comment: They don't relate to each other at all and are independent.

Comment: And yes they happen one after the other, not in parallel.

Comment: Since they are independent, you cannot simplify the answer beyond what I wrote.

Comment: Also we must be assuming these are the ONLY two steps, or all other steps take constant time. Of course if there are three steps and the third one takes $O(n^2m^2)$ the answer would be wrong.